# Android camera - when to call autofocus() and cancelAutoFocus()?

Tags: android

In my Android app, I am using FOCUS_MODE_AUTO for the camera. This is the only focus mode that is working reliably for me. Here is how I call autofocus() initially.

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
   this._camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
   this._camera.startPreview();
   this._camera.autoFocus(null);
}
```

Once auto-focussed, there are two cases when the focus needs to be reevaluated - when I move the device and when I move the content. At present, I am using SensorEventListener and calling autoFocus() once I detect a little bit of motion on the device. However, this will not catch the case of moving the content while the device is stationary. I am thinking I could use a 500 ms timer and keep calling autoFocus(). Just wondering what others are doing.

The other question I have is when do you need to call cancelAutoFocus().  From the documentation, once auto-focus succeeds, it is not supposed to auto-focus again until cancelAutoFocus() is called. However, at present I am not calling cancelAutoFocus() at all and things seem to work. What gives? Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with SensorEventListener and our customers are liking it. Anytime the user wants to refocus, they simply need to shake the device a little so that autofocus() can be invoked once again.